# Java: Number of Randomly Generated Zeroes

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, count, whitespace

I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to get Java to count the amount of zeroes in the randomly generated list of numbers that goes until it reaches either "-10" or "+10."

I'd appreciate any help,

Thank you.

My Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomWalk 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int position = 0;
        int stepsTotal = 0;
        int zeroesTotal = 0;

         while (position !=10 && position != -10) {
             if (rand.nextDouble() < 0.5) {
                 position--; 
             }
             if (rand.nextDouble() < 0.5) {
                 position++; 
             }
             else {
                 zeroesTotal++ ; 
             }

             stepsTotal++;

             System.out.print(" " + position); 
         }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("The final position is: " + position);
         System.out.println("The number of steps taken is: " + stepsTotal);
         System.out.println("There are " + zeroesTotal + " zeroes." );
    }
}
```

Example output: (I count 4 zeroes, not 21.) (What's it even counting?)

0 0 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 3 3 4 3 4 3 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 6 6 6 6 5 5 6 7 8 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 8 9 9 8 7 8 9 9 9 10

The final position is: 10

The number of steps taken is: 58

There are 21 zeroes. (Where the error is)

Comment: It doesn't look to me like your code is doing anything similar to your problem statement: "I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to get Java to count the amount of zeroes in the randomly generated list of numbers that goes until it reaches either "-10" or "+10."" Please revise - what are you expecting to see in your output?

Comment: I am expecting to see "There are x zeroes." with there being the correct amount of zeroes as outputted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're incrementing `zeroesTotal` if the position is actually at `0`. Also, there's no need to generate two random numbers per iteration of your walk.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    int position = 0;
    int stepsTotal = 0;
    int zeroesTotal = 0;

     while (position != -10 && position != 10) {
         if (rand.nextDouble() < 0.5) {
             position--; 
         }
         else {
             position++; 
         }

         if (position == 0) {
            zeroesTotal++;
         }

         stepsTotal++;

         System.out.print(" " + position); 

     }
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("The final position is: " + position);
     System.out.println("The number of steps taken is: " + stepsTotal);
     System.out.println("There are " + zeroesTotal + " zeroes." );
}
```

Comment: Added explanation.